# bash .tar creation

Tags: bash, backup, tar

I try to create a .tar.gz with files or directories in parameters to do a backup.

However, when i create .tar.gz archive, i have this error :

```
tar: path_directory_1: cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: path_directory_2 : cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Stopped with failed status due to previous errors
```

How I built the archive:

```
tar zcvf $dirbackup/backup-$backupDate.tar.gz $string
```

where `string` is:

```
old_IFS=$IFS

IFS=$'\n'

string="";

for line in $(cat $1); do

      string="$string $line"

done

IFS=$old_IFS
```

`$1`: file with paths directory and paths file to save.

Exemple of `$1` content (just directories paths to save):

```
~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/web
~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/communication/
```

---

Result with set -x :

```
+ tar zcvf /var/backups/mesbackups/backup-09-11-2016-13-58/backup-09-11‌​-2016-13-58.tar.gz '~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/web' '~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/communication/'
tar: ~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/web : cannot stat : No such file or directory 
tar: ~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/communication : cannot stat : No such file or directory 
tar: Stopped with failed status due to previous errors
```

---

When I run this command in shell that's work ...

```
tar zcvf /var/backups/mesbackups/test/backup-09-11‌​-2016-13-58.tar.gz ~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/web ~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/communication/
```

How I can do with my script ? That seems work without quots no ?

Comment: Could you post the actual `tar` invocations? Use `set -x` in Bash, see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/847373/edit) to add details. The commands cannot be read well in a comment.

Comment: [Useless use of backticks](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks)

Comment: I use it to read line by line in my file ($1) @DavidFoerster

Comment: I know what you're using it for. I'm saying that it's an [anti-pattern](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) and should be replaced with a superior solution (see “[Useless use of backticks](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks)”).

Comment: Also bear in mind that having `IFS` set to the empty string results in different behaviour than not setting `IFS` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Analysis

Looking at the input file examples

```
~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/web
~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/communication/
```

and the error messages from `tar`

```
tar: ~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/web : cannot stat : No such file or directory
tar: ~/Documents/MIAGE/L3/semestre5/communication : cannot stat : No such file or directory
```

you seem to presume that either the shell interpreter or `tar` will expand the tilde (`~`) when reading its lines with either of the following constructs:

- `for i in $(cat infile)`
- `while read i; do ...; done < infile`
- `mapfile ... < infile`

This presumption is false. None of the common shell interpreters performs *[expansion](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)*, or more specifically *[tilde expansion](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion)* in these situation. It only evaluates escape sequences (see [`read`](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read)). No known (to me) implementation of `tar` performs argument expansion either (and it shouldn't since that would create many issues).

### Solution

You need to expand the tilde characters in your input files somehow.

The easiest way is probably to change the input file manually or with a filter (if you can be certain that `$HOME` doesn't include `sed`'s escape or delimiter characters (here `\` and `;`)):

```
sed -e 's;^~\(\/\|$\);'"$HOME"'\1;' infile | tar cvzf my-archive.tar.gz --from-file -
```

If you want to take advantage of all available shell expansions and can **assure proper input escaping** you can use the *[`eval` built-in command](//www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval)*:

```
while read -r i; do
  eval echo "$i"
done < infile |
tar cvzf my-archive.tar.gz --from-file -
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was `~` on my file, it must be replaced with an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

If `$1` is the name of a file containing a list of files to add to the archive, one per line, then you should be able to just use the `--files-from FILE` form of `tar`

```
tar zcvf "$dirbackup"/backup-"$backupDate".tar.gz --files-from "$1"
```

If you can't use `--files-from` for some reason, then the next best option is probably to use a bash array

```
mapfile -t files < "$1"

tar zcvf "$dirbackup"/backup-"$backupDate".tar.gz "${files[@]}"
```

although this may have issues if the number of files in `$1` is very large.

Comment: Same errors with your two solutions.

Comment: Actually, the next best alternative to `tar ... --files-from "$1"` is `xargs tar ... < "$1"`. The main reason why someone doesn't have `--files-from` is because they're not using GNU tar which makes it likely that other GNU tools like Bash are missing too. `xargs` should be there nonetheless.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, same errors with `xargs` so archive is empty (even if it is create).